# Mechanize in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby, mechanize

I am adept in Ruby WWW::Mechanize. And I was wondering if a jQuery equilavent exists ?

Comment: What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: I want to remotely Post credentials (login/password) to an url. Using www::Mechanize I'm able to do it on the server side. But I wan't to do it on the client. By the way I'm a total jQuery newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a crazy question after all!  Take a look at this link.  Mr. Anand sort of injects JQuery into his Mechanize page object, then uses JQuery pretty much in-line.

http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-internet-explorer-with-jquery/

Don't get distracted; it's a fascinating blog.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really an equivalent of this because of what it does.  Mechanize going to various sites, the very basic requirement for what it does simply isn't allowed in JavaScript for security reasons.  Making cross-domain requests is blocked by something called the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can't make requests (and get the data back, through the request gets there) from a domain different than the one of the page you're on, this is to prevent malicious JavaScript from doing things like spam `https://mybank.com` with login attempts, among many other examples.

If you want something besides Mechanize for your needs, you'll have to either customize a browser and kill the SOP security, or look outside the browser like you're already doing...but since the policies are there by default, I don't believe any JS framework like this exists (that I've ever seen/heard of anyway).